# casperjs trying to find xpath and echo a statement but not working

Tags: xpath, phantomjs, casperjs

Here is my code I just cannot get it to find the xpath I just cannot figure it out.

I have tried this below with no success I can use it for css selector but I cannot use that in this instance I need to find the xpath.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('https://example.com/stat.go', function() {
if (this.exists('/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[3]/span')) {

    this.echo('we are here');
}
});

casper.run();
```

Any help would be appreciated I just cannot figure it out thanks in advance

Here is the html i am aiming to see if it exists

```
<td align="right" class="formheadings">Opted In</td>
```

i am trying to make sure this part of html exists if it does i want a message echoed.
if it doesnt i want the same but a diffrent message

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="420" class="account_table">
    <tr>
        <td class="formheadings"><strong>BT broadband option:</strong></td>
        <td class="formheadings" align="right">BT Total Broadband Option 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="formheadings"><strong>BT Wi-fi community status:</strong></td>
        <td class="formheadings" align="right">Opted In</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td class="formheadings"><strong><!-- BT Wi-fi minutes used:--></strong></td>
        <td class="formheadings" align="right">0</td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
        <td class="formheadings">
            <a href="&lt;!--http://bt.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13929--&gt;" target="fuplimits" onClick="window.open('','fuplimits','toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=760,height=610,left=50,top=50,titlebar=yes')"><!--BT Wi-fi fair usage policy--></a></td>
        <td class="formheadings" align="right"> 
            <a href="/static/wa/wifi/pages/info.html" target="tnc" onClick="window.open('','tnc','toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=450,height=500,left=50,top=50,titlebar=yes')">Terms and conditions</a></td>  
    </tr>

</table>
```

full html

http://pastebin.com/ac6wF7y4

Comment: What are you trying to parse?

Comment: i am trying to just verify that that xpath exists and echo a statment to tell me if it does or not

Comment: I mean could you paste a snippet of the data you're trying to parse. Also, what exactly is not working? Does it echo nothing while your xpath is supposed to point to an existing node? Please update your question with some more information.

Comment: i have include a snippet of the html i am looking for

Comment: That doesn't really help... Your xpath `/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[3]/span` may be wrong, but without the data structure we can't tell. Also, how an xpath looking for a `span` could catch a `td`? And again, what precisely is not working?

Comment: i know this is not wrong as i got it using firebug :)

Comment: there you go some more html

Comment: @Robin also when i say it is not working i mean it does not find it i want it to find it and echo a message if it finds the xpath

Comment: 1) Sometimes browsers add nodes to fix faulty html, but casper most certainly doesn't. ALSO, your xpath is pointing to a `span` node and you're looking for a `td`, it has no way of catching what you're looking for. So your xpath IS very probably wrong. And this snippet of html, since it doesn't show the whole structure of the page and you ARE using the whole structure in your xpath,is also useless. 2) What you want is to echo sth IF the node you want is present.So what's not working is,I guess since that's not really what you said,that the node you want is present and it doesn't echo anything.

Comment: You may want to look at a few xpath tutorials to solve your issue/understand how to clarify your question.

Comment: i will add the full page source in one moment. The exact thing i want to do it Check to make sure that 1 line of HTML exists and echo me a statement saying either Found or Not found

Comment: Please do **not** erase your question to replace it with the answer. The whole point of stackoverflow is to help other people as well as yourself: what's helpful about an answer without a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  `this.exists('//td[@align="right"][@class="formheadings"][text()="Opted In"]')`.

Comment: okay so i need to encorperate it within another script and the page is already loaded so i am using it a a seperate function and it dont need a url as the page is already loaded

Comment: casper.wait(9000, function() { //this.echo(this.getHTML()); if (this.exists('//td[@align="right" and @class="formheadings" and text()='Opted In']')) { this.echo('alive'); } });

Comment: this gives me a sytax : parse error within my already working script

Comment: Parse error because of unescaped single quotes. Check edited answer.

Comment: [error] [remote] findAll(): invalid selector provided "//td[@align="right" and @class="formheadings" and text()="Opted In"]":Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12

Comment: it needed a css path ive fixed it but also eaccepted your answer as you was a great help

Answer (score 0):

i used this to fix my script and check if a css selector exists

```
if (this.exists('div.box_pink div.inner p')) {
this.echo('the css selector exists'); } else { 
this.echo('the css selector dont exist'); 
} 
});
```